# Medical image processing using DICOM images

Tags: python-3.x

Im new to medical image processing. how can i convert 3D DICOM medical images to numerical matrix format using either python or c++?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pydicom package in python. You can install it in python by:

```
pip install pydicom
```

Here is a simple example of reading DICOM images and converting to numpy array:

```
import os
import pydicom
import numpy as np

dicom_dir = your_dicom_folder_of_slices
file_names = os.listdir(dicom_dir)
file_names.sort()

dicom_data = []
for name in file_names:
    path = os.path.join(dicom_dir, name)
    dicom_data.append(pydicom.read_file(path))

array = [data.pixel_array for data in dicom_data]
array = np.stack(array, axis=-1)  # or 0 if 'channel_first'
```

Here is a detailed [example](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/auto_examples/image_processing/reslice.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you really want "3D" dicom image support (ie CT/MR/NM/PET 3d series - as opposed to purely 2D image handling) and you want do anything really 3d related and/or more complex, you might want to check out [simple ITK](http://www.simpleitk.org/).

That gives you very powerful true 3d handling and is fast (it's wrapped around complied C).  It includes, for example, full 3D image registration and various filters/tools etc.

It can read an entire series at once and automatically create a fully spatially aware 3D numpy array for you (ie it takes care of processing all the dicom 3D spatial orientation/spacing etc tags for you)

However, because it's a lot more powerful than pydicom, it also has a much steeper learning curve - but does have many examples and online jupyter notebook tutorials.

...so, depending on your needs it might be good for you.  However, if you only really want basic 2d image-at-a-time type processing, pydicom is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using SimpleElastix for medical image processing. it has many methods for segmentations and many other helpful methods. it is available in both python and C++. In my experience SimpleElastix handled DICOMS and niftis better than other Packages.